# Почему PHP cli не вылетает по таймауту, а виснет?

Tags: php, linux

Короткий php скрипт загружает файл с сервера на YouTube, используя Google PHP SDK.

Случайно и непредсказуемо, иногда этот момент зависает наглухо.

Файлы небольшие, нормальная загрузка длится не больше 5-10 секунд.

Ставил `set_time_limit(30)`, в php.ini тоже прописал max_execution_time 30 cекунд – всё равно процесс php, бывает, висит, пока его не прибить снаружи.

Есть ли красивый внутренний способ бороться с этим, или только извне контролировать, чтобы процесс не висел дольше X секунд?

Answer (score 3):

потому что в <strike>php-cli нет серверного таймаута</strike>, rtfm, но дефолтный лимит установлен в 0. @Sergiks прав. А поскольку php сам по себе однопоточный, то и способа "красивого" нет.

Теория: если зависание происходит во внешнем процессе, то и таймаут не срабатывает (из-за однопоточности). Можно попробовать запускать скрипт скачивания в бэкграунде.

можете попробовать хаки и псевдохаки, в виде какого-нибудь запуска процесса-киллера в бэкграунде с передачей ему pid родителя

ну или https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2007/01/12/running-a-background-process-in-php/, впрочем, любой google запрос со словами php background task подойдет

p.s. виснет скрипт потому, скорее всего, что у вас не настроен (или криво настроен) какой-нибудь таймаут для sdk/curl

p.p.s. насколько я понимаю, sdk позволяет загружать видео кусками

p.p.p.s из красивых хаков - посмотри robo.li, мы юзаем для параллелизации тестов

Comment: Вы не правы, утверждая «в php-cli нет серверного таймаута, rtfm» – это не так. Упомянутые в вопросе директивы `set_time_limit()` или `ini_set('max_execution_time', 10);` учитываются в php cli. Проверил: `<?php set_time_limit(3); for(;;){}` вылетает через 3 секунды с ошибкой "PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 3 seconds exceeded". Есть тонкости в том, какое время считается, а какое нет. Напр. `sleep()` не учитывается за время работы.

Comment: исправил, подозреваю, curl виснет. надо конечно, разбираться, что там использует api

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте через обертку на bash:

```
#!/bin/sh
( your_command ) & pid=$!
( sleep $TIMEOUT && kill -HUP $pid ) 2>/dev/null & watcher=$!
wait $pid 2>/dev/null && pkill -HUP -P $watcher
```

Своровано здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11056286/1299307
Плюсовать туда если что :)

Comment: красиво, спасибо!